# Custom base year for indexed analysis

Tags: r

I have vastly different data in magnitude for different units of analysis. Since I am interested not in the absolute numbers, but the trends I'd like to index the data for better comparison.

I managed to produce a code that indexes the value of 1997  (start of my analysis) as basis 100,but I would like the value in the year 1999 to be of value 100, since the values diverge in the year 2000.

I have created the following example to illustrate my problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(case = c("USA", "USA_synth", "CAN", "CAN_synth"),
                 country = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                 synth = c(0, 1, 0, 1),
                 "1997" = c(1, 1, 0.75, 0.75),
                 "1998" = c(1.1, 1.1, 0.9, 0.9),
                 "1999" = c(1.2, 1.2, 1, 1),
                 "2000" = c(1.3, 1.3, 1.1, 1.1),
                 "2001" = c(1.3, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5),
                 "2002" = c(1.5, 1.6, 1.3, 1.6),
                 "2003" = c(1.7, 1.7, 1.7, 1.7)
                 )
df <- pivot_longer(df, cols=4:10, names_to = "year", values_to = "data")
df$year <- as.factor(c(1997:2003, 1997:2003, 1997:2003 ,1997:2003))
df$country <- as.factor(df$country)
df$synth <- as.factor(df$synth)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(case) %>%
  mutate(idx_vlue = cumprod(c(100, (100 + data[-1]) / 100)))
```

The basis for each case is then 100 for the year 1997, but I am at a loss to get 1999 to be the 100 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who has trouble with adjusting the base, it is as simple as follows:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(case) %>%
  mutate(idx_vlue = (100 + (data - data[which(year == 1999)]) / 100))
```